# Is it possible to get the image mouse click location with PHP?

Tags: php, image, mouse, click, location

Basically what the title says...

I need to have an image that when clicked, I call script.php for instance and in that PHP script file, I get the image coordinates where the mouse was clicked.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
After a couple of answers I realized I didn't describe my problem correctly... The thing is, I don't have total control over the HTML. The control I have for the image and the image link is the control BBCode provides me.

Basically want I want to do is to have a forum signature with links to various sections on my website. You could argue I could use multiple images but most forums limit how much you can type for the signature, which is not enough for multiple images.

So, I will only be able to do something like this:

```
[url=http://www.mydomain.com/script.php]
[img]http://www.mydomain.com/signature.jpg[/img]
[/url]
```

Which translates to something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/script.php">
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/signature.jpg" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't:

1. use JavaScript, or
2. use input type="image", or
3. add any attributes to your img tag (to do things like create an image map)

then, no, you won't be able to do what you describe.

Answer (score 4):

If you use an input type="image", which works like a button, it will send you x and y coordinates of the mouse click (submits form too).

More info here: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html#image

Long time since I used it, but I did make it work for a "where's the ball?" competition on a site many years ago.

Update:

Sounds like the environment is just too limited to do what you want. If the forum lets you do an image map that would work, but I doubt they'd let you. Only other things I could think of would be flash or javascript, similarly, they prob won't allow them. You need something with a little more smarts than an image and an anchor to make this work.

Comment: I can't do that :( I just updated my post with more info on my problem.

Answer (score 3):

if you set the image input `name="foo"`, then `$\_POST['foo\_x']` and `$\_POST['foo\_y']` will be set to the image coordinates.

Comment: I tried that for the <img> tag but it didn't work. But I suppose that your suggestion was something in the lines of seanb's answer? If so, the same info on my updated post also applies.

Comment: BBCODE won't let you do what you want. There has to be a <FORM>. The image has to be an <INPUT type="image"> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using 
[W3C Image Maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.6)

> Image maps allow authors to specify
>   regions of an image or object and
>   assign a specific action to each
>   region (e.g., retrieve a document, run
>   a program, etc.) When the region is
>   activated by the user, the action is
>   executed.

But on a forum in BBCode, I really don't think you're going to be able to get what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible unless you can add inline event handlers to the url in bbcode.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, though not for BBCode is to use the ismap attribute for img.  But may be valuable to others needing exact coordinates. Example:

```
<a href="link.html"><img src="shapes.jpg" alt="Shapes" ismap="ismap"/></a>
```

The x and y coordinates will be passed as GET parameters to link.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use an ajax request when "onclick" is performed to send a request to "script.php".  Otherwise I would read up on php, which is a server-side language.